# How to sort a WPF Listview by a specific colum when a button is clicked

Tags: wpf, listview, sql-order-by

So, i have a Listview that contains some data from a database, and i need to sort data by Class column when i press the OrderBy Button. Can anybody helm me with this?
Below is a print screen of the screen.

http://imgur.com/31cNRfT

The xaml for the button is : 

                
                    
                        -->
                         -->

```
                    <GridViewColumn Header="TimeLine"       DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding TimelineID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Segment No. "   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = SegmentID}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Session Id"     DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding SessionId}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Gun Start"      DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding IsGunStart}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Record Time"    DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CountTowardsTotalTime}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Comp No" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding CompetitionNo}"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Lap No."        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = LapNo}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Segment Time"   DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = LapTime, Converter = {StaticResource timeSpanConverter}}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Deleted"        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = Deleted}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Invalid"        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path = Invalid}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Source"         DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Source}" />
                    <GridViewColumn Header="Hits"           DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding RFID}" />

                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>
```

and for the button:

Margin="0,0,5,0" BorderThickness="0" 
                     HorizontalAlignment="Right" HorizontalContentAlignment="Center" Click="btnSortStandings_Click">

```
                    <ToggleButton.ToolTip>
                        <TextBlock>Order by Class</TextBlock>
                    </ToggleButton.ToolTip>

            </ToggleButton>
```